# No notification about SSL handshake exceptions in Spring

Tags: java, spring, ssl, interceptor

I'm using Spring-boot to set up a SOAP WebService, using SSL with client authentication. I need to perform an operation whenever an SSL handshake fails. Problem is, that I get no notification about that on my server.

I am using Spring-boot with Maven in the version 1.3.1.RELEASE.
SSL is set, by simply defining it in the Spring application.properties file.

Is there any interceptor I can add with an @Bean annotation or something similar, to just get noticed about any SSL exception?

**EDIT:**

I just managed to get the SSLHandshakeException shown in the logs and realized, that it is not raised from Spring itself, but from the underlying Tomcat.

Comment: Are you using https? Post your https or 443 connector in main post.

Comment: Also, elaborate on `SSL is set, by simply defining it in the Spring application.properties file.`